# How to set multiple values for a key in a hash in prototype.js?

Tags: prototypejs

How to set multiple values for a key in a hash in prototype.js?
For Eg:

```
var hash={2005: [107, 31, 635, 203, 2]}
```

Answer (score -1):

you can take exactly what you have written and convert to a Hash like this

```
var hash=$H({2005: [107, 31, 635, 203, 2]});

console.log(hash.get(2005));

//returns [107, 31, 635, 203, 2] as an array
```

Comment: i need to generate that hash with key 2005 and add multiple values to that key.

Comment: So instead of having 1 array as the value of 2005 you need multiple numbers as the values for 2005? That kinda goes against having an associative key=>value Hash. Can you give some more details about how you are using this as there might be a completely different way to handle the code.